# why does i keep getting undefined from the file Object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

hey i quite noob so i need some help plz...

i am building an API that only a registered user can upload a card with image of his asset for rent ..

1. at cards.js i have a post request that should response the saved card..
2. at cards.js inside the post request i made console.log(req.file) to check if i got the file details and i get an 'Undefined'
3. it have something to do with the async function?

i cannot understand why the req.file is undefined .. i tried so many things already , i sure its something stupid ... please try to help..

my front end should be in react.js but for now i didnt built it yet..
just for now i'm using ejs..

my code :
app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config();
const users = require('./routes/users');
const auth = require('./routes/auth');
const cards = require('./routes/cards');



mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/rent_asset', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useCreateIndex: true
}).then(() => console.log('Successfuly connected to MongoDB...'))
.catch(err => console.error(err));



app.use(express.static('./public'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use('/api/users', users);
app.use('/api/auth', auth);
app.use('/api/cards', cards);

const port = process.env.PORT ;
http.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
```

cards.js

```
const express = require('express');
const _ = require('lodash');
const router = express.Router();
const { Card, validateCard, generateRandomNumber } = require('../models/card');
var multer = require('multer');
const auth = require('../middleware/auth');
var fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');


router.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    Card.find({}, (err, items)=>{
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send('An error occurred', err);
        } else {
         
          res.render('imagesPage', { items: items });
        }
    });
});

var storage =  multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) =>{
        cb(null, 'uploads')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
        
    }
    
});


var upload = multer({ storage: storage });


router.post('/', auth, upload.single('assetImage'), async (req, res)=> {

console.log(req.file);

const { error } = validateCard(req.body);
if(error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);



let card = new Card({
    assetName: req.body.assetName,
    assetDescription: req.body.assetDescription,
    assetAddress: req.body.assetAddress,
    assetPhone: req.body.assetPhone,
    assetImage: {
        data:  fs.readFileSync( path.join(__dirname + '/uploads/' + req.file.filename)),
        contentType: 'image/png'
    }, 
    assetNumber: await generateRandomNumber(Card),
    user_id: req.user._id
});

let post = await card.save();
res.redirect('/api/cards');

})

module.exports = router;
```

card.js

```
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const multer = require('multer');
const _ = require('lodash');



const cardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    assetName: { type: String, enum: ['House', 'Apartment', 'Hotel room', 'Residental unit', 'Special asset'], required: true},
    assetDescription: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 2, maxlength: 1024 },
    assetAddress: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 2, maxlength: 400 },
    assetPhone: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 9, maxlength: 10 },
    assetImage: { data: Buffer, contentType: String },
    assetNumber: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 3, maxlength: 999999999, unique: true },
    user_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }

});

const Card = mongoose.model('Card', cardSchema);

async function generateRandomNumber(Card){

    while(true){
  
      let randomNumber = _.random(1000, 999999999);
      let card = await Card.findOne({ assetNumber: randomNumber });
      if( ! card ) return String(randomNumber);
  
    }
  
  }

  function validateCard(card){

    const schema = Joi.object({
      assetName: Joi.string().min(2).max(20),
      assetDescription: Joi.string().min(2).max(1024),
      assetAddress: Joi.string().min(2).max(400),
      assetPhone: Joi.string().min(9).max(10).regex(/^0[2-9]\d{7,8}$/),
      assetImage: Joi.object()
    });
  
    return schema.validate(card);
  
  }

exports.Card = Card;

exports.generateRandomNumber = generateRandomNumber;
exports.validateCard = validateCard;
```

imagePage.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Image Uploading</title>
</head>
 
<body>
    <h1>To Upload Image on mongoDB</h1>
    <hr>
    <div>
        <form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div>
                <label for="assetName">Asset title:</label>
                <select id="name" value="" name="assetName" required>
                    <option value="House">House</option>
                    <option value="Apartment">Apartment</option>
                    <option value="Hotel room">Hotel room</option>
                    <option value="Residental unit">Residental unit</option>
                    <option value="Special asset">Special asset</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="assetDescription">Asset description </label>
                <textarea id="assetDescription" name="assetDescription" value="" rows="2"
                          placeholder="Description" required>
                </textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="assetAddress" >asset Address</label>
                <input type="text" name="assetAddress" id="assetAddress">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="assetPhone" >asset Phone</label>
                <input type="number" name="assetPhone" id="assetPhone">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="assetImage">Upload Image</label>
                <input type="file" id="assetImage"
                       name="assetImage" value="" required>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
 

</body>
 
</html>
```

Comment: There is a lot of code here, at least point out where the code is showing undefined.

Comment: One thing I could find in your code, you are using req.file, it should be req.files.

Comment: in cards.js  i have a post request and after that i should get the image file that the user uploaded from the form..   after the post request i made console.log(req.file) and i get undefined..  on the browser just after i submit the form i get a message: "cannot POST"

Answer (score 0):

try to change the name you pass in the single method to "file" like so

```
 upload.single('file')
```

Comment: that didn't work ..inside the single brackets should be the name of the field .. in my form the name is: "assetImage".

Comment: true and you're trying to console log the file which does not exist.